# Fix array column when 'Updating Item' action

Tags: power-automate

I have a SharePoint List which is linked to a Power Automate flow.

In my SharePoint List, I have multiple columns which are classed as 'Choice'.

However, in my Power Automate flow, when I have the action to 'Update Item', one of the Choice Columns is classed as an array? I have highlighted it in red in the below screenshot. When hovering over the clipboard-looking icon in the item/column that is the issue it states **'Switch to detail inputs for array item'**.

I do not have this issue with any other of my Choice Columns, and it is creating issues down the line where when I add any additional action past the 'Update List Item', it automatically puts the actions under `Apply to Each`, which I do not want.

I tried recreating the flow, and also checking the SharePoint list, which confirms that it is a 'Choice' column. However, the issue still persists.

See above photo where it shows which parts of my flow the apply to each functionality is being added automatically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: … and the column definitely isn’t setup as multi choice?

Comment: It is multi choice yes - Is there a way of keeping it as a multi choice without having it apply to each?

Comment: Can you show us where it's adding the `Apply to each`?  You haven't shown that.

Comment: @Skin I have added a second photo which shows the affected actions in my flow.

Comment: You've redacted the part that creates the loop.